# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access a property from my constructor function, but I keep on getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined." The property that I am trying to access is the array this.possibleX. Please advise. Thank you!

```
var Item = function() {
    this.x = this.positionX();
    this.y = this.positionY();
    this.sprite = this.spritePic()
    this.possibleX = [0,100,200,300,400];
    this.possibleY = [80,160,240,320];
    this.spriteOptions = ['images/Rock.png','images/Rock.png','images/Rock.png','images/Heart.png','images/Gem Blue.png', 'images/Gem Green.png', 'images/Gem Orange.png'];
}

Item.prototype.positionX = function() {
    var startX = this.possibleX[Math.round(Math.random() * this.possibleX.length)];
    return startX;
}

var item = new Item();
```

Comment: What did you try so far? The error message is pretty straightforward: this.possibleX is not defined.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Look to the right of this comment, in that area, there is a Related section with 10 questions, all with the same error message.

Comment: I'm new to javascript. I thought it was an access issue because the "this" variable wasn't used properly, so I was learning about call, binds, and apply to work my way around it, but it doesn't seem like it was the right approach. Thanks for your helpful comments! New here and love the community already! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var Item = function() {
    this.x = this.positionX();
```

Notice how you are first calling the function and then defining `this.possibleX = [0,100,200,300,400];`. You need to invert this order.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me save a lot of time! Cheers